# Proving that a polynomial is irreducible over a field

Tags: polynomials

What's the general strategy to show that a particular polynomial is irreducible over a field?

For example, how can I show $x^4 - 10x^2 -19$ is irreducible over $\mathbb Q$?

Comment: $\mathbb Q[x]$ is *not* a field. We usually say that a polynomial is irreducible *over* a field $k$ when it is irreducible in the ring $k[x]$.

Comment: See for instance http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rational_root_theorem and http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Factorization_of_polynomials#Factoring_over_the_integers_and_rationals

Answer (score 24, accepted):

When a polynomial is integer valued, one may appeal to Gauss's lemma which states that if the coefficients of a non-constant polynomial $f$ are relatively prime and $f$ is irreducible in $\mathbb{Z}[X],$ then $f$ is irreducible in $\mathbb{Q}[X].$

This allows you to use the structure of $\mathbb{Z}[X]$ which is richer than that of $\mathbb{Q}[X]$ to prove irreducibility. For example for every prime $p$ there is a reduction map from $\mathbb{Z}[X]$ to $\mathbb{F}_p[X].$ If the reduction of $f$ is irreducible over $\mathbb{F}_p[X]$ then $f$ is irreducible over $\mathbb{Z}[X].$

Note that for your polynomial, $x^4 - 10x^2 - 19 \mod 3$ is irreducible in $\mathbb{F}_3[X].$ Hence, $x^4 - 10x^2 - 19$ is irreducible in $\mathbb{Z}[X].$

Answer (score 10):

There is no "general strategy" that works for all polynomials and fields, but there are several useful results which can be found [here](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Irreducible_polynomial#See_also).

Answer (score 6):

Suppose that $p$ is a fourth degree polynomial which is not irreducible. Then $p$ contains a linear factor or a quadratic factor.

In your case you can easily check using the abc-formula that $p$ does not have a linear factor, i.e., it does not have a root lying in $\mathbf{Q}$.

Thus, now you have to think about why $p$ doesn't have a quadratic factor. You could do this with brute force, i.e., write out $p = (a+bx+x^2)(d+ex+x^2)$ and get to a contradiction. (This used to be $(a+bx+cx^2)(d+ex+fx^2)$, but as lhf points out it's clear that one may assume that $c=f=1$.)

Easier would be to  apply one of the methods mentioned by Ragib Zaman.

Comment: You may assume $c=f=1$.

Comment: Of course. I'll edit that.