# Irreductibility of a polynom

Tags: ring-theory, irreducible-polynomials

I have to show that $p(x)=x^5+5x+11$ is irreductible on $\mathbb{Z}[x]$ both using and not using Eisenstein.
I have been trying to translate $p(x)$ or searching a field $\mathbb{Z}p$ but can't reach anywhere even with Eisenstein

Comment: Try to factor it $\pmod 3$.

Comment: Non-standard but nice criterion given by Osada (see [this answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/443612/proving-irreducibility-of-x6-72/2768357#2768357)) applies here because $11$ is a prime and $11>1+5$.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can use Eisensteins criterion on $p(x-1)$. Without using Eisenstein, you could note that
$$p(x)\equiv x^5+2x+2\pmod{3},$$
which is irreducible as it has no roots in $\Bbb{F}_3$, and the three irreducible quadratics $x^2+x+2$, $x^2+2x+2$ and $x^2+1$ do not divide it.