# Is $x^4+22x^2+1$ irreducible over $\mathbb{Q}$?

Tags: abstract-algebra, polynomials, irreducible-polynomials

I am wondering if $f(x)=x^4+22x^2+1$ is irreducible over $\mathbb{Q}$.

To do this, we use a variant of Gauss's lemma. If $f(x)$ is irreducible over $\mathbb{Z}$, then $f(x)$ is irreducible over $\mathbb{Q}$. Now, I read a comment here [https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/68764/proving-that-a-polynomial-is-irreducible-over-a-field#:~:text=For%20example%20for%20every%20prime,Z%5BX%5D](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/68764/proving-that-a-polynomial-is-irreducible-over-a-field#:%7E:text=For%20example%20for%20every%20prime,Z%5BX%5D) that said if there exists a prime $p$ so that the reduction of $f(x)$ is irreducible over $\mathbb{F}_p$, then $f(x)$ is irreducible over $\mathbb{Z}$.

So my question is: how do I choose my prime $p$ *and* once I choose my prime $p$, how do I show that the reduction of $f$ cannot be broken down into smaller polynomials? Would a proof by contradiction be best? Let me know. Thanks!

Comment: There is, in general, no easy way to pick a prime.  You could, of course, just try various small primes. Alternatively, you could note that there are no rational roots so all you need to rule out are quadratic factors.

Comment: To answer the question in the title: "yes". Is there a reason you want to do this by hand? Any computer algebra system (for instance [sage](https://sagemath.org)) can quickly do this for you.

Comment: For Galois theory reasons, polynomials of this form are in fact reducible modulo every prime: https://math.stackexchange.com/a/160855/41415
So if you want to show $x^4 + 22x^2 + 1$ is irreducible, you'll have to use a different method.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

once you see that there are no rational roots, the possible factorizations are, with some integer $a,$
$$  (x^2 + ax + 1)(x^2 - ax +1)  = x^4 + (2-a^2) x^2   + 1$$  or
$$  (x^2 + ax - 1)(x^2 - ax -1)  = x^4 + (-2-a^2) x^2   + 1$$

where the $22$  does not work.